# iPhone unable to call a certain contact

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

Ok this is really weird and I’d appreciate any guidance.

In the last few days I have been unable to call one contact, my wife. My phone can call all other contacts and numbers that I’ve tried. I can call her over FaceTime audio and WhatsApp no problem. We can text fine. She can call me fine.

When I try to call her my phone makes no noise whatsoever. Other calls the would be a click before ringing a few seconds later. When I try to call her, nothing.

Confirmed that she has not blocked my contact or have any call forwarding setup.

I’ve tried restarting my phone (and hers) numerous times. On recommendation of my network provider (Vodafone in Ireland) I’ve reset network settings, which gave me increased 5G coverage actually, but made no impact, still cannot call.  Their next suggestion was a new SIM card?

Any tips really really appreciated !

Cheers

Comment: Does it show as an incoming call if she's watching the screen as you call? That could potentially be a silent [or broken] ring-tone set for just you.

Comment: No. Having both phones in my hand, she’s does not ring, mine doesn’t even seem to connect to the network

Comment: I'd get back onto your phone provider then. [One last shot… try dialling manually, with & without the country code.]

Comment: did you try to put your SIM in another phone?